# How to use DataTrigger From Enum property?

Tags: wpf, enums, binding, textbox

So i have this `Enum`:

```
public enum Status
{
    Intermediate = 0,
    Valid,
    NotValid
}
```

My `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyData
{
   private Status _status;

   public Status Status 
   {
       get { return _status; }
       set
       {
           _status= value;
           OnPropertyChanged();

       }
}
```

My TextBox `Style`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Status.Valid}" Value="True"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSeaGreen" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

So this `Status` property is changing and i verify the it become `Valid` but still my `TextBox` `Background` color not changing.
This `style` is define in other `ResourceDictionary` file.
The name of this file is `TextBox.xaml`.

Other properties works fine, the reason i am asking is that i never try to write `Trigger` with `enum` so i even dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Valid"/>
```

Or

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="{x:Static local:Status.Valid}"/>
```

...where `local` is mapped against the CLR namespace of `Status`.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

Comment: Which one worked?

Comment: Middle one worked for me.